# ClassNotFoundException in JDBC program despite of adding driver's JAR file

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, java-11

I am writing a simple program in Java using to demonstrate insertion of data in MySQL table using JDBC. But the program is generating ClassNotFoundException while registering driver.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }    
}
```

I have added the driver JAR file in the same directory.

**To compile the program:**

```
javac -cp ".:~/Programs/D/friends/assignment/driver.jar;" test.java
```

**To execute the program:**

```
java -cp ".:~/Programs/D/friends/assignment/driver.jar;" test
```

**O/p:**

```
ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

[image]

Comment: `driver.jar` is the library for the MySQL JDBC stuff? And what reason has the trailing semicolon after "…/driver.jar"?

Comment: And you know that an explicit registration of the driver is not necessary when you use a current version of the JDBC driver?

Comment: @tquadrat Yeah right, it is the JDBC driver of MySQL and the trailing semicolon is for the reason that while setting classpaths we separate two different classpaths using a semicolon. And I know the fact that it is not necessary to register driver but I was doing so because while creating connection the code was raising exceptions. And so I explicitly registered driver to confirm if the driver is being registered or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** The issue is caused by **;** at the end of the driver.jar and also not using fully qualified path.

**Windows based OS** uses **;** separator whereas **Unix-based OS** uses **:** separator.

**Solution :**

1. First compile the code : `javac test.java` (Run this command)
2. Run the code without semi-colon : `java -cp .:<fully-qualified-path>/driver.jar test`

Sample output :

```
anish@Anishs-MacBook-Pro ~ % javac Test.java
anish@Anishs-MacBook-Pro ~ % java -cp .:/Users/anish/driver.jar Test  
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
```

**Note :** I'm using **mysql-connector-8.0.15.jar**. If you are using the same or greater, then change from `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` as that class is deprecated.

Comment: B I tried your method but that is raising another exception.


**Error: Could not find or load main class test Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test**

Comment: @ShashankShekhar You didn't compile. First compile as I have shown

Comment: I have attached the screenshot in the question now. Please refer to that.

Comment: @ShashankShekhar Please share the path of the jar. fully qualified path

Comment: After reading your comment, I tried to run the program using a fully qualified path and it worked. Your method worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228316/discussion-between-shashank-shekhar-and-anish-b).

Answer (score 2):

1.at the end of the classpath there seems to be an extra semi-colon:
`/assignment/driver.jar;"`
try without it

2. Are you sure `driver.jar` is the correct file?
normally they are called like `mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar`

Comment: I renamed that for my convenience.

Comment: And I tried without the semicolon and now it's raising a new exception.

**Error: Could not find or load main class test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test**

Comment: so it is a different problem/question - maybe add the directory to the package containing `test.class` to the classpath

Comment: and colon `:` is the separator for non-Windows systems; semi-colon `;` for Windows (since `:` is used for drive specification)

Comment: Actually, I didn't know that before. But now I got the concept of semi-colon separator. Thanks for sharing that.